# ADB error: cannot connect to daemon

Tags: android, adb

I need help to get ADB working on my PC (win7 64bit) with the Samsung Galaxy S2.

I have installed the drivers coming along Kies, I think under sub folder "25_escape".
The drivers appear correctly as "Samsung ADB interface" under the device manager.

When I run "adb devices" I get the following logs

```
>adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
** daemon still not runningerror: cannot connect to daemon
```

I'm wondering if it is a driver issue, or something else.
I have several other android phones that are working just fine (HTC, Motorola, Samsung Galaxy S1 even works) but that issue is happening on the Galaxy S2 (and Tab 10.1 as well).
I disabled windows firewall, and it is still stuck. I made sure Eclipse is not running and I tried to kill ADB from the task manager, but none of that helped.

Your help is really appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: What does adb devices say when your tablet it plugged in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same issue for me. Was stumped. After I removed "Dell PC Suite" the problem went away.

Comment: Dell PC suit was causing this issue for me too. Un-installing PC suite solved it.

Comment: Thanks. Luckily, adb continues to work with a Dell device (in my case, Streak 5"), even after uninstalling the "Dell PC Suite"!

Comment: Anyone know what else could be causing the same problem like Dell PC suite did. I had this problem before and it went away after uninstalling Dell PC suite, but its come back again and there's no Dell PC suite on my PC now!

Answer (score 61):

Go to windows task manager and end process tree of **adb**.
It will make attempts to start adb.

Sometimes on Windows **adb kill-server** and **adb start-server** fail to start adb.

Comment: It's worked for me. this solution should be marked as answer.

Comment: Yes !! worked for me as well, it should marked as answer

Comment: Upvoted for a simple and solid solution. Recommended.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I have uninstalled EVERYTHING and installed again but does nothing.

Comment: Unknown host service

Answer (score 10):

If nothing works **Restart your PC** . **Restarting my computer does the trick**

Comment: Why down vote, it happened in my case installed drivers of LeTv 2 were not reflected till I reboot my PC.

Answer (score 7):

I face this problem on daily basis, so to resolve this I kill adb.exe by executing following command :

```
taskkill /f /im adb.exe
```

Note : You should have administrative rights to execute the above command.

Answer (score 6):

Powershell:

```
net stop winnat
net start winnat
```

and then

```
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 4):

This answer may help some.  The adb.exe has problems with virtual devices when you are using your phone for tethering.  If you turn off tethering it will correct the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that Kies is installed, but not running.

On your phone make sure you have USB Debugging mode enabled.

If still not successful, disable any Antivirus software.

Answer (score 1):

I can solve my problem, i'm install a new firewall and it's reason of my problem, when i uninstall it my problem is solved. because of a lot of viewed of this question, i suggest you to check your firewall and antivirus that give permission for your Android Debugger Bridge.

Answer (score 1):

Check your firewall and antivirus for permissions for Android Debugger Bridge (adb.exe).

Answer (score 1):

I've finally solved a very similar issue!

In my case, the problem was that I had two different SDKs (one from Eclipse and the other from Android Studio), so I was trying to execute the ADB commands in the wrong one.

So it is important that you check the path you are using in your IDE and execute the commands on the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had a couple of things open that prevented ADB from properly running. Specifically, I had BlueStacks Tweaker (to kill BlueStacks which runs in the background) and another program. Both use their own bundled adb.exe version for issuing commands. I was then also using my system's adb.exe. I had to close the other two programs in order to solve the problem. Restarting my computer would've also solved the problem (by closing those programs for me lol).

Answer (score 0):

I was using Genymotion 2.9.0. I updated to 3.0.0 
Now it is working. So please check Genymotion version.

Answer (score 0):

So I was getting this problem and found that a process called dcb was running an older version of adb.  So I renamed the folder /usr/local/var/dcb to /usr/local/var/OLDdcb and it was recreated automatically and I was able to successfully run my tests in the emulator.  [image]

Answer (score 0):

If the above methods did not work, (such as restarting, killing, rebooting, reconfigure, updating, permissions .. etc) the bug might be in the last opened files tab. I had a file I was accessing from `data/data/...` and whenever I opened A.S, the panel always showed the error. Just close the tabs and restart AS.

Answer (score -1):

Delete you AVD and create another. Maybe isn't the perfect thing to do, but it's the fastest.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on my ubuntu.
I just ran adb from `sdk/platform-tools` instead of pre-installed version on my system and it worked fine.