# Problem with the emulator since the update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I have had a problem with my emulator Android Studio for a few days, when I try to compile my code, my event log marks this:

```
09:13   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44088 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

09:13   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 44088 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

09:13   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
```

What can i do to fix this
thank you in advance

Comment: am off the topic but please let me know what's your pc RAM

Comment: 16 go de Ram en tout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with adb.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56198290/problems-with-adb-exe)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android emulator errors (socketTcpLoopbackClientFor and AdbHostServer.cpp)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000072/android-emulator-errors-sockettcploopbackclientfor-and-adbhostserver-cpp)

Comment: are you on windows? check if you have proxy enabled.

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE:** This issue has been fixed in version `30.0.26` as mentioned [here](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/08/emulator-30026-canary.html). The temporary fix mentioned below may not be needed anymore.

---

Yes, this issue is seen in version `30.0.12` of android emulator.

As a temporary fix, which will work only on emulators without PlayStore, disable Multi-core cpu option

`Avd Manager -> Select emulator -> edit -> Advanced Settings -> Multi-core CPU -> UNCHECK this option`

The devices with PlayStore images do not allow changing anything about the device this won't work.

I have not seen any major lag by disabling the multi-core cpu option. Emulator is just as responsive and loads under 2 seconds, ready to be used.

Tested on Ryzen 5 1600, 16gb RAM, Windows 10 Pro, emulator 30.0.12.

Comment: unfortunately it didn't work, I still have the same error as before

Comment: downgrade to version 30.0.0

Comment: I am using emulator version 30.0.12-6466327 and I am facing similiar issue. My Android is 9.0 (Pie) - API 28. My application runs properly but get infinite "Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 62900 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)" on Event Log. I have installed and uninstalled numerous AVD and always getting this issue. AIt seems it just have to double the value of FD_SETSIZE. I opened a question asking why so many connections to same emulator and ir may be worth https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62125502/why-so-many-connection-to-same-emulator-port-with-established-and-time-wait

Comment: @JimC the issue is found in versions above >30.0.0. so downgrade to 30.0.0. Comment if you have any issue downgrading. I looked at your post, you can't edit mult-core option in emulators with play store image. In my testing version 30.0.0 works fine with all images.

Comment: @Doc I am quite new to Android development. What is the diference between emulators with Play Sotre image and others?

Comment: @JimC you get google play installed. Only the emulators with this support can use these images. You see a google play icon on emulator with the support. Also there are images with google api and others without it. google api images have preinstalled google apps and other functionality.

Comment: @Doc thanks a lot. It is my first project in Android. I am facing many challenges. Kindly, if possible, take a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62185020/is-it-possible-to-disable-the-daemon-started-by-default-when-starting-android-st asking if I can disable such automatic daemon startup mentioned here

Comment: @JimC sorry, using flutter on linux. windows for very specific task.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275242/13711025 open this link. I have already submitted an answer for this same error in the previous question. Just download or update the amd processor and other few contents in the sdk manager. Always update the sdk plugins frequently. Use nexus device for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same errors with some more, too. I am using flutter for development and when I used the *flutter doctor*, I found that some Android licenses were missing and just after I accepted them all, the errors were gone. So, check the licenses or reinstall the SDKs.

If you are specifically using flutter, I would suggest upgrading (or reinstalling) the flutter package and make sure you have turned on "Windows Hypervisor Platform" if you are using an AMD processor.

**[UPDATE]**: I'm getting the same errors back. Now, found a workaround rather than a solution. I installed Android Studio 4.2 Canary 7(Latest) along with my Stable build and opened the emulator from it and didn't get any errors. So, I'm opening the emulator from Canary and running the project on emulator from my regular Stable Android Studio.

It seems that some issues exist with the current stable build of Android Studio and they are fixed somehow in the latest Canary build.

Check out: [Emulator 30.0.12 Canary Changelogs](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/05/emulator-30012-canary-psa-if-emulator.html)