# android emulator not responding

Tags: android, android-emulator, avd-manager

i just installed android studio newly and i also installed the emulator just now but the emulator doesn't respond, i have installed `HAXM` i have turned on my Vt-x i have done all the necessary things to be done but it still doesn't respond.

here is how it shows
[image]

it doesn't respond to clicks,or anything.
if it helps it also shows these errors

```
Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 48276 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
Emulator: dsound: warning: Voice is not capturing
```

thanks i appreciate a lot!!!

Comment: have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885421/problem-with-the-emulator-since-the-update)

Comment: @SanjayRavichandran i cant find any useful answers

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of hustle and bustle i solve with this strategy:
just turned on show window frame and turned it back off and everything started responding well.
1. click on the three dots at the end of your emulator 
2. go to settings
3. turn on `show window frame around device`
4. turn it back off and it works

[image]

thanks for all the contributions!!!