# Android emulator errors (socketTcpLoopbackClientFor and AdbHostServer.cpp)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I just installed Android Studio (Windows) and I created a google pixel 3 XL, API 29, no play store installed.
When I launch an hello word application, I get these 2 errors:

```
Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 52252 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: AdbHostServer.cpp:102: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
```

For what concerning the first error, I tried this [Problem with the emulator since the update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61885421/problem-with-the-emulator-since-the-update) but it didn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problems with adb.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56198290/problems-with-adb-exe)

Comment: @BilalAbdeen no

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an AMD processor, you must activate "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors" included in SDK Tools.

After this, the emulator operates normally. If error is present yet, it don't stop the emulation

Comment: No, I am using an Intel CPU

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is helpfull but I will share my experience as a possible answer. I struggled for three days trying to face a very similar issue as yours. And in my case it was working properlly until that. I created a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094629/emulator-emulator-error-adbhostserver-cpp102-unable-to-connect-to-adb-daemo) but I din't get answer yet. Well, I tried all I found around. Then I read somewhere someone facing issues with emulator and just downground it and it fixed it. I just tried downgraded from Android 10+ to Android 10 and to API #29 and I got a complete diferent issue. Than I tried again to Android 9 and API #28 and it fixed my issue.

One more thing it can be usefull. I noted that before I downgraded Android/API I had many more for this list

```
C:\Users>netstat -ano | findstr "5037"
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:49735        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:51843        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:51855        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:51859        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:51867        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49735        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     9604
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51843        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     13184
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51855        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     9604
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51859        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     9604
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51867        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     9604
```

And maybe checking you SDk Tools installed can help also

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the following stuff I mentioned in the pic.
2. Make sure you are using any nexus emulator which is good for a performance boost.
3. Update the plugins frequently to avoid these errors.

[More Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Az9Od.png)

Comment: I did what you suggested but same errors still occour

Answer (score 0):

I finally have found a kind of workaround for this. This is a problem caused by the now latest stable version of Android Studio(4.0.1).
I fixed this by downloading Android Studio 4.2 Canary 7 build, installing it. Then, running the emulator from it, followed by using that emulator in my primary Android Studio.
I advice you not to work on your project from the Canary itself, as it has many unknown bugs, and you will regret working.
Feel free to ask any more doubts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on Android Studio 4.0.1 and resolved it by deleting the plugins located in C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Google and installed Android Studio 4.1 RC 1
https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html