# Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 52396 above FD_SETSIZE (32768) but the Emulator seems to run properly

Tags: android, android-studio, sockets, android-emulator, android-sdk-tools

What these list of errors mean and more important how to fix them? If someone can comment also what possible issues I should expect from that may drive me to some action since it is unclear to me because my application is running and showed properly

I found a question with a bit similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62000072/android-emulator-errors-sockettcploopbackclientfor-and-adbhostserver-cpp/62123108#62123108) but in this case it blocks from starting emulator with "Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037" and in my case the emulator is working (I can navigate and hit buttons properly)

```
31/05/2020
18:55   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0

18:55   Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project C:\WSs\FireStoreDemos\AppFirestore

18:55   Gradle build finished in 752 ms

18:55   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 52380 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

18:55   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 52380 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

18:55   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 52396 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

18:55   Emulator: socketTcpLoopbackClientFor: error: fd 52396 above FD_SETSIZE (32768)

18:55   Install successfully finished in 142 ms.: App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
```

Here is console during startup

```
05/31 18:55:37: Launching 'app' on Pixel 3a API 28.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.mycomp.appfirestore/com.mycomp.appfirestore.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.mycomp.appfirestore.test | com.mycomp.appfirestore
Waiting for application to come online: com.mycomp.appfirestore.test | com.mycomp.appfirestore
Connected to process 8310 on device 'emulator-5554'.
Waiting for application to come online: com.mycomp.appfirestore.test | com.mycomp.appfirestore
Connecting to com.mycomp.appfirestore
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/mp.appfirestor: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/mp.appfirestor: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
W/ActivityThread: Application com.mycomp.appfirestore is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8604', transport: 'socket'
I/chatty: uid=10086(com.mycomp.appfirestore) identical 2 lines
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/chatty: uid=10086(com.mycomp.appfirestore) identical 1 line
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1312)
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:13 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:0
    Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
W/mp.appfirestor: Unsupported class loader
W/mp.appfirestor: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
W/mp.appfirestor: Accessing hidden method Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;->getOpticalInsets()Landroid/graphics/Insets; (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->left:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->right:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->top:I (light greylist, linking)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/graphics/Insets;->bottom:I (light greylist, linking)
V/FA: onActivityCreated
W/mp.appfirestor: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->getAccessibilityDelegate()Landroid/view/View$AccessibilityDelegate; (light greylist, linking)
V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.mycomp.appfirestore, 1:322838517289:android:c8792f2cb4e1fb14ceae38
I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 28000
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.mycomp.appfirestore
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
W/mp.appfirestor: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
W/mp.appfirestor: Accessing hidden method Landroid/widget/TextView;->getTextDirectionHeuristic()Landroid/text/TextDirectionHeuristic; (light greylist, linking)
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1151344
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd8d5af50, tid 8353
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xd8d167e0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd8d167e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd8d06c70)
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd8d5b310, tid 8353
D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xd8d167e0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xd8d06c70)
D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 3 2
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

The Virtual Device I am using

```
Name: Pixel_3a_API_28

CPU/ABI: Google Play Intel Atom (x86)

Path: C:\Users\Cast\.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_28.avd

Target: google_apis_playstore [Google Play] (API level 28)

Skin: pixel_3a

SD Card: 512M

fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile: 

runtime.network.speed: full

hw.accelerometer: yes

hw.device.name: pixel_3a

hw.lcd.width: 1080

hw.initialOrientation: Portrait

image.androidVersion.api: 28

tag.id: google_apis_playstore

hw.mainKeys: no

hw.camera.front: emulated

avd.ini.displayname: Pixel 3a API 28

hw.gpu.mode: auto

hw.ramSize: 1536

PlayStore.enabled: true

fastboot.forceColdBoot: no

hw.cpu.ncore: 4

hw.keyboard: yes

hw.sensors.proximity: yes

hw.dPad: no

hw.lcd.height: 2220

vm.heapSize: 256

skin.dynamic: yes

hw.device.manufacturer: Google

hw.gps: yes

hw.audioInput: yes

image.sysdir.1: system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\

showDeviceFrame: yes

hw.camera.back: virtualscene

AvdId: Pixel_3a_API_28

hw.lcd.density: 440

hw.arc: false

hw.device.hash2: MD5:0e6953ebf01bdc6b33a2f54746629c50

fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot: no

fastboot.forceFastBoot: yes

hw.trackBall: no

hw.battery: yes

hw.sdCard: yes

tag.display: Google Play

runtime.network.latency: none

disk.dataPartition.size: 6442450944

hw.sensors.orientation: yes

avd.ini.encoding: UTF-8

hw.gpu.enabled: yes
```

I would prefer to use Android 10 but I couldn't get it working. I created another [question for that with complete different error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62094629/emulator-emulator-error-adbhostserver-cpp102-unable-to-connect-to-adb-daemo)

SDK Tools installed

[image]

And finally, as far as I understand, all emulator ports:

C:\Users>netstat -ano | findstr "5037"

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:49735        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:51843        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:51855        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:51859        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         127.0.0.1:51867        ESTABLISHED     7892
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49735        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     9604
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51843        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     13184
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51855        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     9604
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51859        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     9604
  TCP    127.0.0.1:51867        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     9604
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue along with the ADB daemon issue by opening the emulator from the latest Canary build of Android Studio, and running my project from the Stable version that I use. It works like a charm.
And as to why it will work, read [this](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2020/05/emulator-30012-canary-psa-if-emulator.html).The FD_SETSIZE issue is fixed on 'Emulator 30.0.12 Canary' which is only available with latest Canary build of Android Studio.

One more tip from looking at your log, try to update firebase/firestore plugin to the latest version available manually if not showing in Android Studio.

Comment: What do you call "Canary build of Android Studio"?

Comment: It's like an alpha build of android studio, where all new features will be available. And most of these builds are buggy.
Check it out at [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) `here`.

Comment: Instructions on installing canary alongside stable [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/install-preview) `here`.